# Add field filepath for multiple Excel file import within Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following Module in Access:

```
On Error Resume Next
 Dim strDir As String
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim I As Long
 I = 0
     strDir = "C:\excelTest\"

 strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.xlsx")
 While strFile <> ""
     I = I + 1
     strFile = strDir & strFile
     Debug.Print "importing " & strFile
     DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "mainTable", strFile, False 'has columnheaders
     strFile = Dir()
 Wend
 MsgBox "Load Finished"
 importExcelSheets = I
End Function
```

This imports the data from the xlsx files within the directory (C:\excelTest). This all works fine, but how can I add an additional field which stores the directory and file?

ie. If I have a file test.xlsx during the import a field is created and the path C:\excelTest\test.xlsx is stored.

Answer (score 0):

After records are imported, run an SQL UPDATE action with criteria that distinguishes those new records from previously existing, possibly a date value. Something like:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = '" & strFile & "' WHERE datefield = #" & <some date input here> & "#"
```